# mouse not working in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: mouse-scroll

My wireless mouse scroll is not working in ubuntu 17.10. It is a Genius brand. I have tried several different solutions from community without getting any result.

Comment: whenever my wireless mouse stops working I remove its battery and put it back in ... just dropping the mouse dislodges the battery on mine ... next plug its USB into a different slot ... sometimes that snaps the OS out of its doldrums ... else confirm the mouse is functional by running it on a friends machine ... else just do an update to assure your drivers are current   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ... as an aside I found that this is a very rugged mouse  `logitech m325` ... welcome to ubuntu